# Understanding the bit shifting in C++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, bit-manipulation

I have to debug a C++ code authored by someone else. I have very little experience in bit shifting and hence this question. Here is the modified(values and unrelated code to the bit shifting) version of the same code:

```
void get16Bits1(const char * data)
{
    cout<<(((uint32_t)((const uint8_t *)(data))[1]) << 8)<<endl;
    cout<<(uint32_t)((const uint8_t *)(data))[0]<<endl;
}

int main(){
   const char * data = "francesmccurdey\0";
   get16Bits1(data);
   return 0;

}
```

prints out:

```
29184
102
```

The part I don't get is the `get16Bits1()` function, casting to `uint32_t` changes the output. When I have this:

```
void get16Bits1(const char * data)
    {
        cout<<((const uint8_t *)(data))[1]<<endl;
        cout<<((const uint8_t *)(data))[0]<<endl;
    }

output is:
r
f
```

I am compiling using gcc compiler on linux architecture: x86_64 and byte order being little endian.

Comment: Short answer:  `uint8_t` is typically a character type.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with bit shifting. It's the difference between printing chars and printing ints.

Comment: I can understand that `f` equivalent is 102 ascii, but why such a huge number for `r` to 29184

Comment: @articSnail Truncation.

Comment: The "huge number" comes from the ` << 8`.

Comment: What is up with `code quoting` that makes it not work for ` << 8`?

Comment: @BenVoigt `<< 8` works for me

Comment: @BenVoigt: You can't leave a space after the initial tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout<<(((uint32_t)((const uint8_t *)(data))[1]) << 8)<<endl;`

`data[1]` is `'r'` which is 0x72 in ASCII.

`0x72 << 8 = 0x7200 = 29184`

For the next line in `get16Bits1()`: `cout<<(uint32_t)((const uint8_t *)(data))[0]<<endl`

This line simply prints the value data[0] as `uint32_t`. `data[0]` is `'f'` which is 0x66 in ASCII (102 in decimal).

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to see the output in hexadecimal?

```
7200
66
```

- http://ideone.com/0tJcsQ